# What is the phonetic transcription of the vowel sounds in these recordings?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, transcription

I'm really interested what those vowels are phonetically, sorry if there's anything wrong with the audio, I recorded it with my phone.

recording 1:

https://voca.ro/1eAvg2BdKK0q

recording 2:

https://voca.ro/1omc4vWgWA6B

recording 3:

https://voca.ro/1oK28sI8GpFp

recording 4:
https://voca.ro/14ejHTxmitmf

recording 5:

https://voca.ro/11GoYJNjAdJD

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ɑ ɛ i o ʊ], in that order. This follows the principle of "closest match", with Esling-centric reference values. It also omits any suprasegmentals, which cannot be meaningfully transcribed on such a small corpus. "o" is a toss-up, the alternative being [ɔ]

Comment: I think it might be something like [ö] or maybe even [ɵ].